# How to make a div/video to always be size of browser window, and stuck to certain position

Tags: html, css, video, size

I would like to know how to make a video or div stuck to a certain position while it will always be the size of the browser window. [Here's](http://whiteboard.is/) what I want.

Their "background" contains a video, and if you drag the size of the browser window, you'll notice that it always resizes the video. This is what I'm trying to make.

Here is my code:

```
#menuContainer{
width:650px;
height:50px;
position:relative;

z-index:3;

margin-top:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;

background-color:rgb(183, 52, 178);
}


#menuLogo2{
height:50px;
width:126px;
}


#menuDevide1{


width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-47.5px;
left:131px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}


#menuDevide2{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-119.5px;
left:260px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}


#menuDevide3{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-191.5px;
left:391px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}


#menuDevide4{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-263.5px;
left:520px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}


#menuBottomline{
width:100%;
height:1px;

background-color:black;

position:absolute;
top:70px;
left:0px

}

#headerBG{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;

z-index:2;

background-color:#ffffff;
height:70px;
width:100%;
}


.menuClick{
color:#000000;

text-decoration:none;

font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;;
}


.menuClick:hover{
color:#999999;
}


#menuPortfolio1{
position:relative;
top:-83px;
left:133px;

width:126;

text-align:center;
}


#menuServices1{
position:relative;
top:-155px;
left:263px;

width:126;

text-align:center;
}


#menuProcess1{
position:relative;
top:-227px;
left:393px;

width:126;

text-align:center;
}


#menuContact1{
position:relative;
top:-299px;
left:522px;

width:126;

text-align:center;
}


#mainOverlapWrap{
z-index:1;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


#video1{   
position:absolute;
top:71px;
left:0px;

min-width:1%;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


#mainOverlay{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;

heightx:100%;
height:100%;

background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/kKXM5/).

Please note, I am using their video as a placeholder. My intent is not to steal their work.

**PROBLEM AFTER THE MAIN ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED**

When I resize my browser, I see this really small little grey edge on the right side. It tends to appear when I'm resizing to the left, but goes away when resizing to the right. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX2vv.jpg) picture shows what I mean. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPhr6/) can be found here. I hope you'll be able to fix this problem!

Perhaps it's best to copy the codes in JSfiddle and put them in files on your computer. The whole thing looks kinda weird in JSfiddle, but not in browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body        {height:100%;  margin:0;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/d939e/3/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/d939e/4/)

So here we go for  tag

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="videoInsert">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoInsert {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Final DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/d939e/5/)

**So now we need jquery for it.**

HTML

```
<div id="video-viewport">
    <video autoplay preload width="640" height="360">
        <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/whiteboard.is/videos/bg-loop-new.mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#video-viewport {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1; /* for accessing the video by click */
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

js

```
var min_w = 300; // minimum video width allowed
var vid_w_orig;  // original video dimensions
var vid_h_orig;

jQuery(function() { // runs after DOM has loaded

    vid_w_orig = parseInt(jQuery('video').attr('width'));
    vid_h_orig = parseInt(jQuery('video').attr('height'));
    $('#debug').append("<p>DOM loaded</p>");

    jQuery(window).resize(function () { resizeToCover(); });
    jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
});

function resizeToCover() {

    // set the video viewport to the window size
    jQuery('#video-viewport').width(jQuery(window).width());
    jQuery('#video-viewport').height(jQuery(window).height());

    // use largest scale factor of horizontal/vertical
    var scale_h = jQuery(window).width() / vid_w_orig;
    var scale_v = jQuery(window).height() / vid_h_orig;
    var scale = scale_h > scale_v ? scale_h : scale_v;

    // don't allow scaled width < minimum video width
    if (scale * vid_w_orig < min_w) {scale = min_w / vid_w_orig;};

    // now scale the video
    jQuery('video').width(scale * vid_w_orig);
    jQuery('video').height(scale * vid_h_orig);
    // and center it by scrolling the video viewport
    jQuery('#video-viewport').scrollLeft((jQuery('video').width() - jQuery(window).width()) / 2);
    jQuery('#video-viewport').scrollTop((jQuery('video').height() - jQuery(window).height()) / 2);
};
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/bZrWk/2/)

Comment: Precisely what I want, but I want to only apply it to the video, or the iFrame in this case. Do you know how to make it like that?

Comment: it is applied to iframe only.

Comment: Yes, but if I understand correctly, you are applying it to html and body as well, in your line `html,body    {height:100%;  margin:0;)`. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Could you make one where it applies to a video? I'm trying it your way but it won't work.

Comment: how you want you video to be embeded?

Comment: As a `<video>` tag, please.

Comment: You got it or still facing some problem?

Comment: Works great, however, if the video itself is larger than the browser, it acts... Weirdly. Please check this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZrWk/) to see what I mean. What I want is the video to also be the size of the browser window.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a problem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention it, but the video on http://whiteboard.is seems to add the rest of the video as you resize the browser window. With that, I mean that the very top and left side of the video are **always** attached to their respective sides. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Alright, I'll give this a whirl and I'll get back at you for further troubleshooting/thanking

Comment: A long and confusing road, but you did it! This is precisely what I want! Thanks, man!

Comment: Oh, I have encountered a small problem! I will edit my post to show what the problem is.

Comment: just use this #video1{   
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:calc (100% - 50px);
}

http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kKXM5/1/

Comment: That may have worked perfectly with the first one without javascript, but it doesn't seem to work with the one I have. Any ideas? Also, should I move this discussion to chat so that we're not clogging up the comments?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50947/discussion-between-gaurav-and-toby-van-kempen)

Comment: It looks like you left the chat room. I'll post whatever you might have missed here.

Comment: Margin didn't work, and I don't think it has to do with the CSS... I removed the properties for the video entirely and it didn't even change or anything. I'm sure I'm editing the correct file this time
Editing #mainOverlay{} does seem to affect the grey layer over the video, so it's not that

Comment: Alright, apparently, the video didn't have a class yet, so I gave it one. I gave it the following code: 

.bgVideo{ 
position:absolute; 
left:0px; 

min-width:1%; 
width:100%; 
height:calc(100% - 50px); 
}
Doing that showed me that the problem could indeed be caused by scrollbars. On the right and bottom were suddenly scrollbars. The right one would disappear after resizing, but the bottom one would only disappear after trying to scroll it.

Comment: I tried doing this with an image, however would not act the same as the video. Could you please help me with doing this with an image?